# Android foreground notification disappears

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I have an ask where my app runs a foreground service. The foreground service Notification will have a play or pause option, clicking which will start or stop the corresponding service (of which the notification is a part of). On stop option click the service will stop and restart on play option click on the Notification.

**Generating Notification in MyService.java**

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.loyout_notification);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, NOTIFOCATION_CONTENT_TITLE);

    if (MYMUtility.myServiceRunning(MyService.class, this)) {
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_play_or_stop, R.drawable.ic_stop);
    } else {
         remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_play_or_stop, R.drawable.ic_play);
    }

    Intent notificationBroadcastIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent playIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationBroadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_play_or_stop, playIntent);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(NOTIFOCATION_CONTENT_TITLE)
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    notificationBuilder.setContent(remoteViews);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID_FOR_NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

**On Myservice being destroyed the notification will still remain**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        stopForeground(Service.STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH);
    } else {
        stopForeground(false);
    }
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(FOREGROUND_ID_FOR_NOTIFICATION, notification);
    stopSelf();

    super.onDestroy();

}
```

**The broadcast receiver is as follows**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (MYMUtility.isMyServiceRunning(Myservice.class, context)) {
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, Myservice.class));
    } else {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, Myservice.class));
    }
}
```

The problem I currently am facing is on starting and stopping of service on the Notification.

A) When the app launches, the service gets started. So clicking on the stop option on Notification will stop the service without closing the notification.

B) On click of the play option on Notification, will start the service (as intended on the receiver) but the **Notification disappears**.

The weird thing is, if I am debugging with breakpoints, then the Notification does not disappear on restart of service (on click of notification play option) but it disappears when I am simply running the app on emulator (without debugging).

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Hello, have you found the reason? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Couldn't find anything concrete here.